# Eclipse building the worskpace blocks the other eclipse operations

Tags: eclipse

While using eclipse a couple of days back i observed that while building the workspace eclipse blocks other operations such as run , maven build etc and puts them on hold for quite some time. Is there a work around for this delay ??

Comment: If the project is not compiled how do you expect it to run?

Comment: you mean that, you can not run other opretaions, while building workspace? Then do building workspace as the backend process...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. As builds, etc. modify the Eclipse file system (resources), it is dangerous to run other tasks that could read the file system (it could be inconsistent, etc.).

The only thing to do is to make sure that the build happens fast (enough). For that, incremental build needs to be enabled (that is fast even for a large number of projects in my machine), and/or the number of open projects has to be limited.